# Reading contents of an Excel spreadsheet that includes empty cells using Python. I need to programmatically ignore empty cells

Tags: python, excel

```
import openpyxl
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
cells = sheet['A1':'B7']

for c1, c2 in cells:
    print("{0:8}{1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))"
```

This code results in a TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.*format*_ .
The spreadsheet contains many empty cells and i would prefer my code ignore the empty cells and code run to completion.

Here is the output using the recommended code:

In [41]: book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Testing.xlsx')

In [42]: sheet  = book.active

In [43]: cells = sheet['A1':'B6']

In [44]: for c1 , c2 in cells:
if c1 and c2:
print("{0:8}{1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))

### Subnet  Mask
10.140.64.0/26
1       3

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 for c1 , c2 in cells:
2     if c1 and c2:
----> 3         print("{0:8}{1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))
4
5

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType._*format*.

The code fails when the first empty cell is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Empty cells have value `None` and you can't give a format length for type `None`, which is why you're getting an error. As a simpler example:

```
>>> "{0:8}".format(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

What you want to do is only print the rows with non-empty cells:

```
for c1, c2 in cells:
    if c1 and c2:
        print("{0:8}{1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))"
```

That will skip rows where both `c1` and `c2` are empty. Adjust accordingly if you want to allow one or the other to be empty or non-empty.